# Can't connect to php in Android Application

Tags: java, php, android, rest

Now I'm working on RESTful API with php and try to connect to it from Android
But I can't connect because it's always catch IOException

here's my Android Code (OnReg is the method when clicked Register Button)

```
public void OnReg(View view)
{
    str_email = et_email.getText().toString();
    str_password = et_password.getText().toString();
    str_fname = et_fname.getText().toString();
    str_lname = et_lname.getText().toString();
    type = "register";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, str_email, str_password, str_fname, str_lname);
}
```

Here's the BackgroundWorker class

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
   Context context;
   AlertDialog alertDialog;

   BackgroundWorker(Context ctx)
   {
       context = ctx;
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params)
   {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      String type = params[0];
      BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
      String register_url = "http://192.168.1.9/register.php";
      if(type.equals("register"))
      {
          try
          {
              //Create data to send to server
              JSONObject dataToSend = new JSONObject();
              dataToSend.put("email", params[1]);
              dataToSend.put("password", params[2]);
              dataToSend.put("fname", params[3]);
              dataToSend.put("lname", params[4]);

              //Initialize and config request, then connect to server
              URL url = new URL(register_url);
              HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
              httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); //enable output (body data)
              httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //set header
              httpURLConnection.connect();

              //Write data into server
              OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
              bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
              bufferedWriter.write(dataToSend.toString());
              bufferedWriter.flush();
              bufferedWriter.close();
              outputStream.close();

              //Read data response from server
              InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
              bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
              String line;
              while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
              {
                  result.append(line).append("\n");
              }
              bufferedReader.close();
              inputStream.close();
              httpURLConnection.disconnect();
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
              return "Network Error";
          }
          catch (JSONException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      return result.toString();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
      alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle("Status");

  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result)
  {
      alertDialog.setMessage(result);
      alertDialog.show();
  }
```

Here's my PHP Code

```
<?php
  $m = new MongoClient();
  $db = $m -> ETESS;
  $collection = $db -> members;
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $email = $data->email;
    $password = $data->password;
    $fname = $data->fname;
    $lname = $data->lname;
    $encrypted_password = md5($password);
    $document = array(
       "email" => $email,
       "password" => $encrypted_password,
       "fname" => $fname,
       "lname" => $lname
       );
    if($collection -> insert($document)) 
    {
       echo "Registered Successfully !";
       $response["result"] = "success";
       $response["message"] = "Registered Successfully !";
       return json_encode($response);
    } 
    else 
    {
       $response["result"] = "failure";
       $response["message"] = "Registered Failed";
       return json_encode($response);
    }
  }
?>
```

I already added this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

with all of these code I always get "Network Error" when I clicked Register Button (I assume that it's catch IOException) but when I tried to send POST request by Advanced REST client, everything work perfectly.

Please kindly check my code if there are any mistake.

Thanks

Comment: why there's no `e.printStackTrace();` in `IOException` catch block?

Comment: Add a call to print stack trace then post the output

Comment: Indeed. And change return "Network Error"; to return "IOException: " + e.getMessage();. Add such a return to the other catch too.

Comment: Still Network Error

Comment: MD5 and all cryptographic hash fuctions are not encryption.

Comment: Just using a hash function (such as MD5) is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security leaving the users vulnerable. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: `Still Network Error `. Impossible. You are not serious.

Answer (score -1):

Now I try to connect 192.168.1.9/register.php in browser in my mobile, and it's said

> You don't have permission to access /register.php on this server.

I use wamp as web server

Thanks

Comment: Add additional information to the question (so it is complete), not to a comment.